# Trying to execute 2 queries at the same time : only one works

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I am trying to excute 2 queries once the users likes a post.

first query (works fine) : update +1 to table.
2nd query (doesnt work): insert user's id + post's id in new table.

See below:

```
if($_POST['id'])
{
$postid=$_POST['id'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$like_record=query("SELECT likeid from post_likes  WHERE postid='$postid' and       
userid='$id'");

if (!($like_record))

{
$table = query("INSERT INTO post_likes (id, postid, userid) VALUES ('','',          
'')", $postid, $id);
$table = query("UPDATE postlist SET post_likes=post_likes+1 WHERE postid='$postid'");
    }
?>
```

The 2nd query does not update at all: my current table post_likes is empty. 
Also, no error gets displayed but when i use  print_r($_POST); i can see that the post id got passed correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the `query()` function defined?

Comment: How many rows are you getting back?

Comment: What columns are in `post_likes` and `postlist`?

Comment: There also seems a discrepancy between your query() function calls, where the second call has parameters $wishid, $id, but the others don't.

Comment: What happens if you remove the single quotes from $postid in the second query? Assuming postid is defined as an integer, you don't need to have quotes around it.

Comment: instead of query execute, just echo the update query and try it manually, if it works then you have something with PHP, if you got error, you'll have a good sign :)

Comment: @AdamWenger in post_likes, there are only 3 columns : like_id, postid and userid.  In postlist, there are id, postid, time, post_likes.

Comment: @hjpotter92 the query functions is defined in my config.php file. it's the fist time i run into an issue with it.

Comment: @AdamWenger oops sorry, that's a mistake from me when i created this post, i just edited my post.

Comment: @AndrewGibson, thanks !! I removed the parameters of my 2nd query and it now works !!

Answer (score 0):

According to these description, I suppose your query returned some object instead of array, so !($like_record) did not hit.

Would you please paste query() here?

Comment: Thanks for your help. FYI, I removed the parameters in my 2nd query (and used the $id and $postid variables instead) and it now works!